# Programmatically letting my transition manager know where im coming from or where im going? Swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation, transition

So i have this code in my animateTransition func:

```
    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
      // Getting the reference to container, toView & fromView
      let container = transitionContext.containerView
      let fromView = transitionContext.view(forKey: .from)! // Force unpacked
      let toView = transitionContext.view(forKey: .to)! // Force unpacked

      // Setup for the 2d animation
      let offScreenRight = CGAffineTransform(translationX: container.frame.width, y: 0)
      let offScreenLeft = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -container.frame.width, y: 0)

      // Start the toView to the right of the screen
      container.addSubview(toView)
      container.addSubview(fromView)

      // Get the duration of the animation
      let duration = self.transitionDuration(using: transitionContext)

      // Perform the animation
      UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.8, animations: {

        fromView.transform = offScreenLeft
        toView.transform = .identity

      }, completion: { finished in

        // Tell our transitionContext object that we've finished animating
        transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
      })

    }
```

And if im trying to present a viewcontroller with the help of the transitionManager, which is containing this func, it can't find the from view. If i'm trying to dismiss, it can't find the to view. How can I tell it where it comes from in the present, and how can i tell it where it has to go when dismissing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I found the solution. The reason i wasn't able to reach the fromView or the toView depending on dismiss or present was because i called:

```
let fromView = transitionContext.view(forKey: .from)! 
let toView = transitionContext.view(forKey: .to)!
```

Instead i should call:

```
let fromView = transitionContext.viewController(forkey: .from)!.view!
let toView = transitionContext.viewController(forkey: .to)!.view!
```